# Directly using pure JWPlayer (JS) in Wordpress (Not WP Plugin)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jwplayer

First of all, I'm not using WP JWPlayer Plugin. (And i don't want it. And thats the another story)

---

Well in the Template file:

```
<div id='myJWPlayer'></div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jwplayer("myJWPlayer").setup({
        playlist: "http://www.example.com/playlist.xml",
        listbar: {
                position: 'right',
                size: 250
        },
        width: 700,
        height: 400
    });
});
</script>
```

It is not working, since **even** the `jwplayer("myJWPlayer")` call is **not** being triggered.

---

**Note: This codes are perfectly working in pure HTML files.**
Any idea please?

Comment: See My answer it seems that you have forgotten to close the double quotes setup

Comment: let me know if u r still facing the issue :)

Comment: Where are you running this?

Answer (score 1):

---

### **Well use the below Template file:** [YOU FORGOT TO CLOSE THE DOUBLE QUOTES]

```
<div id='myJWPlayer'></div>
<script>


 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jwplayer("myJWPlayer").setup({
//YOU FORGOT TO CLOSE DOUBLE QUOTES 
            playlist: "http://www.example.com/playlist.xml",
            listbar: {
                    position: 'right',
                    size: 250
            },
            width: 700,
            height: 400
        });
    });
    </script>
```

---

### **Also Check your playlist if it is correctly generated**

[how-to-generate-a-valid-playlistxml](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/5972/how-to-generate-a-valid-playlistxml/)

[jw-player-xml-playlist-and-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066251/jw-player-xml-playlist-and-javascript)

### **Also Check out this blog about jwplayer playlist**

[jwplayer-playlist](http://jokeshahaa.blogspot.in/2013/02/jwplayer-playlist.html)

### **If you are interested in wordpress plug-in you can check it here**

[getting-started-with-the-wordpress-plugin](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/31561/getting-started-with-the-wordpress-plugin/)

[jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/)

[wordpress-video-tutorial-how-to-install-jw-player-plugin](http://videomarketing.karding.org/wordpress-video-tutorial-how-to-install-jw-player-plugin/)

Hope Above Information Helps :)

Comment: hi @hitesh, thanks much for your suggestions. Actually the "double quotes" are just the typo only in the question (correct in real codes). And the problem is, (as i mentioned) the Playlist Setup is absolutely correct because those codes are working perfectly in standalone HTML (non-wordpress) pages. (So the XML can also be assumed, ok) **Just that the `jwplayer("myJWPlayer").setup` call is NOT being triggered, like that in WP.

Comment: Don't assume if HTML is correct it is correct in XHTML. In HTML, some tags don't need to be closed, in XHTML, the language that Wordpress use, all tags HAVE to be closed, period, no exceptions.

Comment: Have you tried running `this` in `IE browser`? may be issue is with created `HTML/XHTML` (As addressed by @PieterGoosen ) and Can I suggest you to try with one video first instead of whole playlist just to debug the issue, Also as you are saying that `jwplayer("myJWPlayer").setup` is not being triggered.can you check the debugger and tell me what error it is throwing. if you can provide any `JSFIDDLE` or  demo link it will be very useful to for debugging from my end, To find issue and give accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i need to properly enqueue the JS call in WP way. Not by the normal HTML way like `<script ....js />`. Got answer here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139984/35907